# Use of prepared variables

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

May I use formerly prepared variables in R Markdown/Knitr document?

For example, I first make `g <- ggplot(df,...` in RStudio. It appears as List in Global Environment/Values. Then I want to call it from R Markdown, for example:

````
```{r}
g
```
````

I'd like to have nice R Markdown document, without huge codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using RData: prepare the ggplot and save it as RData, then load it in markdown.

*PreparePlot.R*

```
library(ggplot2)
myPlot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()
save.image("myPlot.RData")
```

*myReport.Rmd*

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r GGPlot}
library(ggplot2)
load("C:/Path/to/myPlot.RData")
myPlot
```
````

Another option is to use `source`:

*myPlotSource.R*

```
library(ggplot2)
myPlot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()
print(myPlot)
```

*myReport.Rmd*

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r GGPlot}
source("C:/Path/to/myPlotSource.R",local=TRUE)
```
````